# Does $\operatorname{product-of-digits}(n)=n/3$ have at least one solution in any bases except for the power of $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, products, decimal-expansion

Define a function $P_b(x)$ as
$$P_b(x)=\text{"the product of digits of x in base b"}$$

Is it true that for any $b\in\mathbb{N}$, except the powers of $3$, there exists at least one positive integer $n$ that satisfy $P_b(n)=n/3$?

For example, in the case of $b=16$, we have $n=24,54,2970$ because $$\begin{array}{l}&P_{16}(24)=1\cdot 8=24/3\\&P_{16}(54)=3\cdot6=54/3\\&P_{16}(2970)=11\cdot9\cdot10=2970/3\end{array}$$

I tried to find solutions for $b\leq 100000$. Most of them were found, but I haven't yet found for $b=16707,94779$; no solution found for $b=16707,n\leq16707^6$ and $b=94779,n\leq94779^5$.

What makes the problem difficult is that there are only a finite number of $n$ that can satisfy this. If $n$ is a $k$ digit number, $P_b(n)\leq(b-1)^k$ and $n\geq b^{k-1}$. So, $P_b(n)=n/3\implies(b-1)^k\geq\frac{b^{k-1}}{3}\implies k\leq\frac{\log{3}}{\log{\frac{b}{b-1}}}$.

**My attempts:**

- For $b\in 2\mathbb{N}$, we have two digit number $n=1\cdot b+b/2$, so this is true for any even $b$.
- For $b=3m-1,m\in\mathbb{N}$, we have two digit number $n=m\cdot b+x$.
- For $b=6m+1,m\in\mathbb{N}$, we have three digit number $n=1\cdot b^2+(4m+1)\cdot b+(5m+1)$.
- In the case of $b=3^k$, $P_b(n)=n/3\implies 3\mid n\implies$the last digit of $n$ in base $b$ is divisible by $3$$\implies 3\mid P_b(n)\implies9\mid n\implies$the last digit of $n$ is divisible by $9$$\implies\ldots\implies 3^k\mid n$. However, this implies that the last digit of $n$ is $0$, and $P_b(n)=0$.

This is my result of $b\leq100000$ whose digit is greater than $3$.
$$\begin{array}{c|r|r}
b&\text{the smallest }n&n\text{ in base }b\\\hline
111&61315056&44\ 92\ 51\ 99\\
171&9989426304&11\ 116\ 136\ 164\ 117\\
291&277687433520&38\ 210\ 229\ 201\ 252\\
489&42981939000&367\ 286\ 364\ 375\\
999&728487513000&730\ 676\ 675\ 729\\
1371&15297465600&5\ 1283\ 690\ 1152\\
2271&2148217774020&183\ 934\ 1913\ 2190\\
2619&67678340184&3\ 2009\ 2236\ 1674\\
2721&1807944879312000&32\ 2670\ 2145\ 1923\ 1710\\
2979&184425289344&6\ 2907\ 1856\ 1899\\
3279&63027219024&1\ 2582\ 3256\ 2499\\
3891&579834488880&9\ 3279\ 1882\ 3480\\
4887&758438820144&6\ 2434\ 3602\ 4806\\
5211&3497208707631600&4\ 3870\ 4533\ 4733\ 3510\\
5787&519014171052&2\ 3923\ 5083\ 4338\\
7299&1494480881088&3\ 6154\ 7207\ 3744\\
7731&6204334299715300896&1736\ 6267\ 6702\ 7114\ 3987\\
11079&7359977315880&5\ 4566\ 9917\ 10836\\
16707&>16707^6\text{ or not exist}\\
16911&505775286533088&104\ 9812\ 14443\ 11439\\
21249&197497042814880&20\ 12424\ 18273\ 14499\\
23889&923571500757948&67\ 17794\ 22398\ 11529\\
25059&27526222159200&1\ 18775\ 20322\ 24048\\
25227&124239347654688&7\ 18632\ 16044\ 19791\\
27891&258476067299736&11\ 25469\ 22074\ 13932\\
30159&6650570175588900&242\ 13333\ 24826\ 27675\\
32679&201107903798340&5\ 24922\ 29694\ 18117\\
32871&10369855581776460&291\ 31790\ 16121\ 23178\\
35031&341247650220540&7\ 32859\ 24494\ 20190\\
35481&389195145360000&8\ 25306\ 21250\ 30156\\
37299&707049339082596000&13625\ 25328\ 18982\ 35979\\
37911&1030916303835264&18\ 34888\ 35892\ 15246\\
42969&136292456717568&1\ 30848\ 36046\ 40857\\
45219&356537315481336&3\ 38709\ 23194\ 44124\\
47451&191176066968896711988&37\ 33671\ 34281\ 39943\ 37356\\
52011&365305056780924&2\ 31018\ 46041\ 42633\\
52167&4061220222560256&28\ 31653\ 42496\ 35943\\
62649&18606111483304800&75\ 41859\ 45578\ 43344\\
63243&180596621753119728&713\ 60541\ 61588\ 22644\\
66699&1150322810219388&3\ 58474\ 50482\ 43299\\
67311&6999295321933200&22\ 63993\ 31720\ 52245\\
69039&87847167941186472&266\ 66196\ 40709\ 40851\\
69177&633981494732400&1\ 63303\ 59380\ 56220\\
70689&1311868845107948520&3713\ 66460\ 32009\ 55362\\
75879&703506233044944&1\ 46307\ 70546\ 71784\\
77391&1416831300621642240&3056\ 50878\ 46296\ 65610\\
77547&34711476672464640&74\ 33744\ 63146\ 73380\\
78759&27319621329237600&55\ 72528\ 46203\ 49410\\
79491&6516703861972992&12\ 77424\ 58404\ 40032\\
81819&21796802712158292&39\ 65059\ 38454\ 74466\\
94779&>94779^5\text{ or not exist}\\
98199&43456370315630400&45\ 87544\ 40435\ 90936\\
98409&46188177128578368&48\ 45739\ 84977\ 82524\\
98451&12091447235911680&12\ 66080\ 71344\ 71244\\
99111&3438347292408211920&3531\ 69668\ 82205\ 56676\\
\end{array}$$
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: For $b=171$ , I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: If you show which bound we have, this would make it easier to find a counterexample. Also, how did you show that we have no solution in the case of a power of $3$ ?

Comment: @Peter Actually, I have checked up to $b\leq10000$ then found solutions for every $b$ except for a power of $3$. For $b=171$, we have $n=9989426304$. Also, I added some details. Check it.

Answer (score 3):

Not a full solution, but I’ll add that

- For $b = (3i - 1)j$ with $i, j \ge 1$ we have a two-digit number $n = (i)b + (ij)$.

  This narrows the potential counterexamples $b$ to those that are a product of primes of the form $3i + 1$ or $3$.  This set has zero asymptotic density.
- For $b = 6i + 1$ with $i \ge 1$ we have a second three-digit number $n = (2i + 1)b^2 + (3i + 1)b + (4i + 1)$.

And here are some two-parameter three-digit families.  Since $b$ is linear in $j$, these solve an entire congruence class for each fixed $i$:

- For $b = (2i - 1)(3(3i - 1)j + 1)$ with $i, j \ge 1$, we have a three-digit number $n = (1)b^2 + ((3i - 1)^2 j + i)b + (2i - 1)((9i - 4)j + 1)$.

  (Solves $b = 6j + 1, 45j + 3, 120j + 5, 231j + 7, \ldots$.)
- For $b = (3i - 2)((3i - 1)j - 2i + 1)$ with $i \ge 2, j \ge 1$, we have a three-digit number $n = (1)b^2 + ((3i - 2)^2 j - 3(i - 1)(2i - 1))b + (2i - 1)((3i - 1)j - 2i + 1)$.

  (Solves $b = 20j - 12, 56j - 35, 110j - 70, 182j - 117, \ldots$.  Too bad the third digit is too big for $i = 1$—otherwise we’d get $b = 2j - 1$ and we’d be done!)
- For $b = i((9i - 3)j - 6i + 1)$ with $i, j \ge 1$ (except $i = j = 1$) we have a three-digit number $n = (1)b^2 + ((3i - 1)^2 j - 3i(2i - 1))b + i((6i - 1)j - 4i)$.

  (Solves $b = 6j - 5, 30j - 22, 72j - 51, 132j - 92, \ldots$.)

Comment: @dodicta Right, fixed.